# How can I remove standard controls in an OpenLayers-Map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I use OpenLayers and want to create another navigation-control in the upper-left side. I know how to add Controls, but this navigation is added at default while creating the OpenLayers-Map. So I want to remove that Control, to add an own. I know already, that the default-control is an OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The map object has a property called `controls` that is an array of `OpenLayers.Control` objects.  If this property is not explicitly set then OpenLayers will assume that you want the default control set, including `OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()`, `OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom()`, `OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser()`, and `OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()`.

To remove `PanZoom` or any other default control, simply set the `controls` property array at the time you construct the `Map` object.  Here is a code example:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
    ]
});
```

Here is a live [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/controls.html).

**Please note** that by setting the `controls` property that you will not get any `Control` objects be default.  Any controls you need must be added manually.

Here is a link to the [source code of the `Map` object](http://trac.openlayers.org/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js) if you want to see how it works for yourself.

Comment: The default controls are here:  http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.controls

Comment: For version 3: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/map.js and https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/control/controldefaults.js and http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.control.html#defaults

Comment: Latest version: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control.html#.defaults

Comment: So to answer the original question, `controls: []` will remove the controls.

Answer (score 5):

Traverse the array of controls and then remove the zoom control

```
map.getControls().forEach(function(control) {
  if (control instanceof ol.control.Zoom) {
    map.removeControl(control);
  }
}, this);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would have expected `map.removeControl(OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom)` to work but apparently not.

Comment: You need to pass a reference of the control object you want to remove. One way to gain access to the reference is to do: map.removeControl(map.controls[x]), where x is the index of the control you want to remove, but this does not seem to work unless you explicitly set the controls as shown in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are out of date in relation to the current verison of OpenLayers which is 7 at time of writing (Dec 2022). Here is an example of how to just add the Zoom control in manually, rather than using the defaults:

```js
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import Zoom from 'ol/control/Zoom';
import { Tile as TileLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import View from 'ol/View';

const map = new Map({
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM(),
        }),
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom
    }),
    controls: [new Zoom()]
});
```

You can check out this official example to show extending from the defaults:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/navigation-controls.html

If you want an example of adding a control to the defaults dynamically this is a good example of that behaviour:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/scaleline-indiana-east.html